# Select-Object append after variable

Tags: powershell

I have weird behavior.
This line works just fine (output => te001):

```
Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "_" -PropertyNames DbVersion, ScriptNumber | Where-Object {$_.DbVersion -eq "1.2.0.0"} | Select-Object {"te"+$_.ScriptNumber }
```

but I need to be after the $_ variable so this doesn't work (blank output):

```
Get-Content $SourceTxtDbFile | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter "_" -PropertyNames DbVersion, ScriptNumber | Where-Object {$_.DbVersion -eq "1.2.0.0"} | Select-Object {$_.ScriptNumber + "te"}
```

Why?

Comment: Is there an object named `001te` (taking your example) present?

Comment: No there is not...

Comment: Then how should that possible work? What do you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: Well, I have Get-Content that reads the file. I am doing here a split by '_' and I am asking Where-Object {$_DbVersion -eq "1.2.0.0"} select those objects..those lines..It perfectly works without appended string at the end..

Comment: I just think that it isnt right concatenation at the end as it at the begging..maybe I need to put some escape char or something..

Comment: The concatenation looks good to me.

Comment: @TobyU I found the clue :) When I used the split, $_ScriptNumber is set up as integer, and therefore when I type some string he cant do anything, while I type under quotes only the int he does addiction. The main question is - how can I force him to put string column $ScriptNumber

Comment: Like this: `"$($_.ScriptNumber)te"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$_.ScriptNumber + "te"
```

to

```
"$($_.ScriptNumber)te"
```

so that `$_.ScriptNumber` is used as a `string` instead of an `integer`

Comment: @TobyU I rushed to give you a vote up, but I ahve Invalid parameters in my output. Just saying Invalid parameters CHANGE {LOGON | PORT | USER} I dont know what is that..